# Why multiple definitions? Why are other references not defined? This is really basic, what am I missing?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, ncurses

I have a small project that I need to compile.  I have one header and one source that I have created and a nearly empty driver.c that includes my header.
Observe:

```
// iol.h
#ifndef __IOL_HEADER
#define __IOL_HEADER
/*  program: iol.h
    date:    5 October 2010
*/

#define UNIX 1
#define WINDOWS 2
#define OS UNIX  
#if OS == UNIX
    #include <ncurses.h>
#elif OS == WINDOWS
    #include <conio.h> 
    #include <windows.h>
 // Function declarations!
#endif
void iol_init(void);
#endif
```

Now my implementation file:

```
// iol.c
#include <string.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "iol.h"
void iol_init(void) {
    #if OS == WINDOWS
        /* no startup required for windows */
    #elif OS == UNIX  
        initscr();  
        noecho();  
        cbreak();
        keypad(stdscr, 1);
 // Implmntn continues....
```

Now the driver that includes my header and provides the main ():

```
//main.c
#include "iol.h"
```

My bash command:

```
gcc iol.c driver.c -l"ncurses"
```

I get back:

```
/tmp/ccmmW6hQ.o:iol.c:(.text+0x83f): first defined here
/tmp/ccwIKUaT.o: In function 'isEscaping':
driver.c:(.text+0xbab): multiple definition of 'isEscaping'
/tmp/ccmmW6hQ.o:iol.c:(.text+0xbab): first defined here
/tmp/ccwIKUaT.o: In function 'initSeq':
..
driver.c:(.text+0x149): undefined reference to 'iol_prnstr'
driver.c:(.text+0x178): undefined reference to 'iol_putch'
..
driver.c:(.text+0x726): undefined reference to 'iol_display'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I just want to get to point where I can compile this, and start ripping my hair out 'cuz of all my seg-faults.  What's the problem in my setup?  I RTFM on the Gnu C Compiler apparently I'm doing what I'm supposed to, which is **declare** stuff in **iol.h**, **define** in **iol.c**, and *use* it in **driver.c** this is pretty trivial stuff maybe I just need a second set of eyes :S
I'm actually getting a *long* list of errors, if anyone thinks that's relevant, I'm happy to post the whole source.

Comment: What is `isEscaping`?  What is `initSeq`?  Where are `iol_prnstr`, `iol_putch` and `iol_display`?  Please consider reducing your code to the smallest possible example that still exhibits the issue.

Comment: they're other routines _declared_ in iol.h and _deefined_ in iol.c.  Those aren't really germane to the solution, as **every** function I've written throws both an 'undefined reference error' as well as a multiple definition error- somethings wrong with the link...  i know I have to manually link in ncurses, which is specific to this project (a cross platform console editor)

Comment: Well, could you at least post snippets of code that match the snippets of your error message?

Comment: Use a makefile, it'll give you faster compilation and better error messages...

Comment: @mathepic: Why would it give better error messages?

Comment: Apparently I'm not qualified to write makefiles or use make- apparently I need remedial gcc training but I really just can't understand the missing link here (no pun intended)

Comment: go ahead and ssh eval@gus-pc.homeip.net

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth because it gives them per-file. Not better per se but more localized.

Comment: go ahead and ssh eval@gus-pc.homeip.net with the password 3valu4tion and look in folder STACK-OVERLFOW-HELP, you'll see assignment 1 and then you'll see test which is a micro model of the big project.

Comment: @Gus: You can just edit your question, and replace the current code snippets with your minimal test case!

Comment: @Gus Crawford: You could use PDcurses on windows and simplify this code. http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @nategoos:  Oh I'm sure there are lots of libraries that are simpler to use and better for lots of reasons... this is actually a college assignment and the whole point of the exercise is _really_ to teach and get us thinking about cross-compilation...

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Thanks for your guidence!  I'm already pasting in my methods and declarations one at a time- sorry for wasting everyones time but one for sure problem is that not everyone from my group has sent me their source yet!  So I had two missing definitions... thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the linker complaining. This is what you would get if you had a function defined in the header file that was not declared 'inline'

the missing ones are because you have not added the correct libraries

Comment: hmmm it verbose lets me know if it can't find a library.  If I compile gcc ... -lncurses without (in my case on ubuntu anyway) libncurses5 the gcc returns a specific prompt telling me so.  I tried gcc ... -lncurses_w, again to no avail- I'll double check but I don't beleive I'm having an issue linking in ncurses but... you never know...

Comment: @Gus: Why don't you temporarily get rid of all the ncurses stuff, and reduce your problem to the simplest possible case?  All this extra stuff is just distracting...

Comment: Okay, well I wrote a simple program with one function and one main() just the same model as above.  No link probelms.  I go into my header implemenation file and even add some ncurses calls and include the header... compile again with no -lncurses, unsurprisingly, a link error with undefined refs to the ncurses functions.... recompiled with -lncurses... no problems.  So my source is germane to the solution indeed... thanks guys.

Comment: @Gus: Right, so all you need to do is add your original code back in one function at a time, until it fails to link.  Then you will have located the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling them separately:

```
$ gcc -Wall -c ioi.c
$ gcc -Wall -c driver.c
$ gcc ioi.o driver.o -o program -lncurses
```

To isolate and fix compilation errors...

Comment: I did try that... let me give you the results...  Nice thinking but to no avail! Each individual compile-only command executes without an error. Adding the wall switch shows me I'm a bit sloppy: its suggesting I parenthesize my assignments as I decide on their condition, shows me some functions that possibly exit without returns, and show me some unused variables... none of these are going to cause a link error though could they?  such that they cause a break in the referencing of the functions? or connecting the declarations with the definitions?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention if you are compiling on Windows or Unix.  If on Windows I suspect that there are order dependencies in the .h files.  Usually you want windows.h first so that it defines constants that the other .h files will use.

Comment: I'm compiling for GCC with a linux distro-